# How to create a model having one to one relation with one model and many to many with other model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model that has many to many relation with `Room` model so one user can be subscribed to many rooms and many users can be subscribed to one room. This relation works fine.

```
# for many to many relationship
user_room = Table('user_room', Base.metadata,
              Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')),
              Column('room_id', Integer, ForeignKey('room.id'))
              )    

class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    room = relationship("Room", secondary=user_room, backref='participants', lazy='dynamic')

class Room(Base):

    __tablename__ = "room"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(200))
    created_date = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

But now I want to add another model which is `Profile` that should have one to one relation with `User` model I tried this:

```
 class Profile(Base):

    __tablename__ = "profile"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    avatar = Column(String(500), nullable=True)
    bio = Column(String(500), default="I like collobrating on Collab.")         
    user = relationship("User", uselist=False, backref="profile")
```

and updated `User` model like this:

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "user"

    # rest of the columns
    profile = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("profile.id"))
```

but that gives the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't 
proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 
'mapped class Profile->profile'. Original exception was: Error creating backref 'profile' 
on relationship 'Profile.user': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class User->user'
```

Comment: You can't backref to `profile` because there is already a `profile` column for the FK.  Try renaming that column to `profile_id`, then the backref should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on user and by using backref instead of backpopulates you can remove the profile relationship.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    profile_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("profile.id"))
    profile = relationship("Profile", backref=backref('profile', use_list=False))
```